# Why should I use gRPC instead of IPC / Simple websocket?

Tags: java, node.js, go, ipc, grpc

I'm sketching an architecture for a micro services system, planned to run currently on one machine (maybe distribution in the future).
The system will be composed of services written in both Node.js, GO and might be Java.
Both node.js and Java will need to pass instructions and receive results from the GO server.

Now, I'm trying to decide should I use IPC pipe or ramp up on gRPC and protobuff and use them.

Comment: First things first: does node have a grpc/protobuf client lib? If not the question is moot.

Answer (score 1):

These are on different abstraction levels and have different uses, as such the 'or' in the question is wrong. **You will need both** types (transport and encoding), even if you reimplement one of them.

IPC like an anonymous or named pipe is usually called a transport, they have no way to encode multiple instructions or results (though they encode a stream of bytes).

gRPC and protobuf need a transport, support multiple transports and add more fine grained encoding (how to represent an integer, a list, etc) and possibly more on top. Technologies that support encoding something can often be nested with a transport or encoding, this is common with technologies that are used together with HTTP, this may make sense but may only add a layer without having a use.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I guess i need to rephrase.